# How to set the default text of JIRA Ticket depending on the ticket type using scriptrunner

Tags: groovy, jira

Is it possible/or how is it possible to set a default text to desciption depending on the tickettype in the create process?

What I want to achive: the user presses "create Issue", if he selects "Problem Report" as a ticket type, in summary should be some default text, that can still be modified. Is this posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Default Values for 'Create Issue' screen](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.gebsun.plugins.jira.defaultvalues/server/overview) plugin that can do this.